# Local chat between empathy and telepathy?

Tags: empathy, kde-telepathy

Empathy and telepathy, both have local chat, or chat for LAN.

How configure local chat for obtain communication between empathy and telepathy clients ?

Clarification: In a LAN, one pc use telepathy and other pc use empathy, both have "nearby people" or "local chat" enabled, but dont appear in chat list. If both uses the same program can change, otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless Messaging is a feature included in the XMPP protocol some years ago: [XEP-0174](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html)

Every client that implements this feature should be able to connect to clients on the same network, I just tested it with gajim on my Linux box and Adium on my Mac, worked flawlessly..

If you have any problems you should check if the `avahi` daemon is installed and running on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but telepathy is the IM framework which empathy uses.

If 'local chat' is the one using Bonjour, then anyone on the local network with a client configured to work with that, will be able to chat with Empathy via that method; including iChat on OS X, where the method originated.